# SQL coding issue, error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'or'."

Tags: sql-server

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and have not got any closer. I get the error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'or'.

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT Pitch.Location_id
FROM PITCH
WHERE (((Pitch.Location_Id) Not In 
(SELECT Location_Id FROM BOOKING
          WHERE BOOKING.StartDate or BOOKING.EndDate    
                 NOT BETWEEN '2014-06-08'  AND '2014-07-08')) AND    
((PITCH.Type_name)='Delux') AND ((PITCH.Available)=1))
```

If I remove the `or BOOKING.EndDate`, the query works perfectly.

Comment: your Q have an answer :), you have to keep seperate `WHERE BOOKING.StartDate 
                 NOT BETWEEN '2014-06-08'  AND '2014-07-08' or BOOKING.EndDate   NOT BETWEEN '2014-06-08'  AND '2014-07-08'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (as @tinka suggested above):

```
SELECT Pitch.Location_id
FROM   PITCH
WHERE  ((Pitch.Location_Id) Not In   
          (SELECT Location_Id FROM BOOKING
           WHERE BOOKING.StartDate NOT BETWEEN '2014-06-08' AND '2014-07-08'
              OR BOOKING.EndDate   NOT BETWEEN '2014-06-08' AND '2014-07-08'))     
           AND   ((PITCH.Type_name)='Delux') AND ((PITCH.Available)=1))
```

Comment: works a charm, ive put this into my php script now and getting issues :/ will post another question

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you should try. Note that the inner query is still in sargable syntax.

```
SELECT P.Location_id FROM PITCH P
   WHERE 
     P.Type_name='Delux' AND 
     P.Available=1 AND
     P.Location_Id NOT IN 
      (
         SELECT Location_Id FROM BOOKING B
           WHERE 
             B.StartDate < '2014-06-08' OR 
             B.StartDate > '2014-07-08' OR 
             B.EndDate   < '2014-06-08' OR 
             B.EndDate   > '2014-07-08'
       )
```

Now the reason why you received that error was because

> WHERE **BOOKING.StartDate or** 
>   BOOKING.EndDate NOT BETWEEN '2014-06-08'  AND '2014-07-08'

is evaluated like `Booking.Startdate` being OR-ed with `BOOKING.EndDate NOT BETWEEN '2014-06-08'  AND '2014-07-08'`. The latter yields a boolean result of true false but the former expression `Booking.StartDate` is not boolean.